# Как сделать ячейку таблицы ссылкой через jquery на jsp

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

Есть ajax запрос

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data: data,
   url: 'ajax_controller',
   success: [function(responseJson) {
       $('#results').remove();
       var $table = $("<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" align=\"start\" id=\"results\">").appendTo($("#matches"));
       $("<tr>").appendTo($table)
       .append($("<td>").text('Логин'))
       .append($("<td>").text('Имя'))
       .append($("<td>").text('Фамилия'))
       .append($("<td>").text('Статус'))
       .append($("<td>").text('Баланс'));
       $.each(responseJson, function(index, product) {    // Iterate over the JSON array.
           $("<tr>").appendTo($table)
           .append($("<td>").text(product.login))) // проблемная строка
           .append($("<td>").text(product.name))
           .append($("<td>").text(product.surname))
           .append($("<td>").text(product.role))
           .append($("<td>").text(product.balance));
       });
    }]
});
```

Мне приходит лист пользователей и информацию о каждом я записываю в таблицу.

Нужно что бы по нажатию на ячейку логина пользователя (проблемная строка). Пользователь переходил по ссылке:

`<a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller?command=go_to_user_profile&login=product.login'> product.login </a>`

В ссылке как вы понимаете параметр "product.login" каждый раз новый.

Может кто-нибудь знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В проблемной строке надо text() заменить на html() и передать туда вашу динамически собирающуюся ссылку:

```
.append($("<td>").html("<a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller?command=go_to_user_profile&login=" + product.login + "'>" + product.login + "</a>"))// проблемная строка
```